# Replace space before and after a particular character - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to replace space before and after a particular character in Javascript?

Scenario: string - "( 'fever' ) OR ( 'cold' )"

I just want to remove spaces before and after single quotes

expected result - "('fever') OR ('cold')"

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Why is everybody down voting this?

Comment: Next time, to avoid the downvotes, add some relevant code of what you tried to achieve the desired result, where you're stuck with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```js
const s = "( 'fever' ) OR ( 'cold' )"

const out = s.replace(/(?:\s+('\w+')\s+)/g, '$1')

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged regex, but sometimes I would just do something like this:

```
function replaceAll(before, after, string) {
  let result = string;
  while (result.indexOf(before) !== -1) {
    result = result.replace(before, after);
  }
  return result;
}
let example = "( 'fever' ) OR ( 'cold' )";
example = replaceAll("' ", "'", example);
example = replaceAll(" '", "'", example);
console.log(example);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaround like this:

```js
const s = "( 'fever' ) OR ( 'cold' )"
const out = s.replace(/(?<=\()\s+|\s+(?=\))/g, '')
console.log(out)
```

Where:

- `(?<=\()\s+` matches 1 or more spaces preceded by an opening parenthese
- `\s+(?=\))` matches 1 or more spaces followed by a closing parenthese

---

You can also use this:

```js
const s = "( 'fever' ) OR ( 'cold' )"
const out = s.replace(/(?<=')\s+|\s+(?=')/g, '')
console.log(out)
```

Where:

- `(?<=')\s+` matches 1 or more spaces preceded by a single quote
- `\s+(?=')` matches 1 or more spaces followed by a single quote